# Two divs with drop shadow on same level

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that have drop shadows and are on the same z-index.

They are currently both casting a shadow on each other.

I would like them to both cast shadows on the background but NOT on each other. How do I do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchimp/5WQc8/ - As you can see the top div is slightly red.

Comment: can you increase the margins or you want it like this only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't have two different element with the same stacking level. Elements always have different stacking-levels. That's why your second Element shadows the first Element. (Without z-index the appearence in the DOM determines the stacking-level)

Z-index works only on non-static positioned elements (relative,absolute) so that won't help either.

IMO you can't achieve the effect you want without some little css-hacking (Declaring a non-static position on the elements combined with an additional wrapper-element - don't declare z-index on the parent but only on the child-elements).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/5WQc8/3/)

But please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. For now I'm going to get rid of the drop shadow on one of the divs. Not ideal but good enough for now! Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Mr_Chimp look at my example and see if this fits your needs.

Comment: I have done, it's a good fix but I'll leave the question open for now just to see if anyone has another approach. As I say, I've avoided the problem for now as it's not a big problem but I am interested to see how people would go about it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mr_Chimp good idea, although I see no other way to achieve this, maybe somebody really comes up with a fancy solution.

Answer (score 9):

Use this simple CSS trick, just create pseudoelement `:after`, set its z-index lower than divs and give a shadow to it. Following code will drop non-overlaping shadows under each `div`. Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/on38a8pz/1/.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer, not the "you can't" one